# Tap on a image inside the ListView, we should get a property value of specific Row

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, cross-platform, gesture, binding-context

I have a listView, it contains an image with a list of items. When I tap on the image, I should get ProfileID of that row.

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" x:Name="{Binding ProfileID}" Aspect="AspectFill">
    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="imageUserGesture_Tapped"/>
    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>

private async void imageUserGesture_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CloseAnimation();
    var img = ((Image)sender);
    var name = img.Name;//How can I read name property ??????
    //var name = e.LoadFromXaml(MatchProfile).Name;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}"
       x:Name="imageUser"
       Aspect="AspectFill">
                                                                
   <Image.GestureRecognizers>
      <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="imageUserGesture_Tapped"
         Command="{Binding TapCommand}"
         CommandParameter="{Binding ProfileID}"
         NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
                                                                
   </Image.GestureRecognizers>

</Image>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`Name` is not an actual property you can reference, it is just a XAML artifact (hence the "x" prefix).  Instead, you can use the `BindingContext` to get the data you need

```
var img = ((Image)sender);
var context = (MyClassGoesHere)img.BindingContext;
var name = context.ProfileID;
```